# Using the value returned from a Future in a class in dart

Tags: asynchronous, dart

Hello i have the following code

```
class TodoProvider {
  Database db;


  TodoProvider() {
    _initDatabase();
    print("Db is >>>>> $db");
  }

  void _initDatabase() async {
    final database = await AppDatabase().connect();
    db = database;
  }

  Future<Todo> insertTodo(Todo todo) async {
    todo.id = await db.insert('todo', todo.toMap());
    return todo;
  }

  Future<Todo> getTodo(int id) async {
    List<Map<String, dynamic>> maps =
        await db.query('todo', where: 'id=?', whereArgs: [id]);
    if (maps.length > 0) {
      return Todo.fromMap(maps.first);
    }
    return null;
  }

  Future<int> deleteTodo(int id) async {
    return await db.delete('todo', where: 'id=?', whereArgs: [id]);
  }

  Future<int> updateTodo(Todo todo) async {
    return await db
        .update('todo', todo.toMap(), where: 'id=?', whereArgs: [todo.id]);
  }

  Future close() async => db.close();
}
```

The AppDatabase is a class that exposes the connect() method which returns a future.

The Goal is to assign the value returned from AppDatabase into the db class variable

Most methods in the TodoProvider class relays on the db class variable to work with the database.

**The problem is that class variable db is always null**

Comment: When you call  _initDatabase, it is an *async* function, and also calling *await*, you have to wait it to finish. While it doesn't finish connection *db* will always be *null*. Maybe the connection you are trying to make is wrong. Try updating your code and show us what is the path to the database, port, if the database is running, etc.

Comment: @Kohls if  i were to await the result from _initDatabase at the TodoProvider constructor method , that would result to an error. How can i get the db variable to hold the data from AppDatabase().connect();

Comment: I don't know what AppDatabase() does, neither connect(), insufficient data to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code right now depends on the `db` variable is being set which happens inside an async operation. There are two ways to fix this:

#### Use static builder method

You can create a private constructor which can be called by a static method which are allowed to return `Future<TodoProvider>` which the user can await on.

```
class TodoProvider {
...
  TodoProvider._(this.db) {
    print("Db is >>>>> $db");
  }

  static Future<TodoProvider> getInstance() async {
    return TodoProvider._(await AppDatabase().connect());
  }
...
}
```

#### Use the Future as member of the class

This is not the prettiest solution but still a way to do it. Since you are allowed to `await` on the same `Future` multiple times, you can just `await` every time you need to access the `Database` object.

```
class TodoProvider {
  Future<Database> _db;

  TodoProvider() {
    _initDatabase();
    print("Db is >>>>> $db");
  }

  void _initDatabase() {
    _db = AppDatabase().connect();
  }

  Future<Todo> insertTodo(Todo todo) async {
    final db = await _db;
    todo.id = await db.insert('todo', todo.toMap());
    return todo;
  }

  Future<Todo> getTodo(int id) async {
    final db = await _db;
    List<Map<String, dynamic>> maps =
    await db.query('todo', where: 'id=?', whereArgs: [id]);
    if (maps.length > 0) {
      return Todo.fromMap(maps.first);
    }
    return null;
  }

  Future<int> deleteTodo(int id) async {
    final db = await _db;
    return await db.delete('todo', where: 'id=?', whereArgs: [id]);
  }

  Future<int> updateTodo(Todo todo) async {
    final db = await _db;
    return await db
        .update('todo', todo.toMap(), where: 'id=?', whereArgs: [todo.id]);
  }

  Future close() async {
    final db = await _db;
    db.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: Were would i call the getInstance() method

Comment: The place where you intend to use the class?

Comment: ok i just placed it on the TodoProvider constructor...... seems to work fine

Comment: Ah ok, I understand now. Yes the private constructer and getInstance() should be put inside the TodoProvider class. Sorry if I did not make that clear :)